# Interract with my program while kivy launched

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, keyboard-events

I'm trying to finish a project where I need to use kivy. My first screen is like a waiting screen, I need to display it while a .mpeg video is downloading. When this video is downloaded, I need to display the second screen which contains the video player.
First I don't know how I can change my screen without a button, I'm trying since a few weeks but have found nothing. But that's not my main problem here.
How can I programm something else to interract with my kv screen while launched? For exemple, if I need to programm a keyboard event, where could I put my lines? If I put them into the class of one screen for example, it will never display it. I know that it's just a logic problem but I can't find any solution...

Here is my current code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import keyboard

# Window.fullscreen = 'auto'

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'loadscr'
    GridLayout:
        name: 'loadscr'
        cols: 1
        rows: 3
        padding: 0
        spacing: 0

        Label:
            text: "Éppen  kapcsolódunk  Magyarországhoz"
            font_size: '50sp'
            font_name: 'hollywoodcapital.ttf'

        Image:
            source: 'bckgrndlogo.png'

        Label:
            text: "Legyen türelemmel..."
            font_size: '35sp'
            font_name: 'asseenontv.ttf'
        
        Button:
            text: ""
            font_size: 1
            size: 10, 10
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: 0, 1000
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

As I've found nothing about how to change my screen without a button, I would like to use a keyboard event, or to click on the button with the pyautogui library. That's why my button is very small. It's not a perfect solution but I need a first launchable version of this project next week.

So, where could I put my lines about keyboard event or the click with pyautogui?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems like a rather absurd XY problem - you can't work out how to change the screen without a Button so you're trying to have a tiny button and inject an event? That's a much harder solution, changing the screen is easy, simply set the `current` property of the ScreenManager to the value you want, when you want. The real question is: when do you want the screen to change?

Comment: It doesn't work with the current property, I've tried a lot of times and I think I made a subject about this. I want to change my screen when my video file is upload.

Comment: And I would like to create a button or to inject an event. I just wanna know how can I write something else than my screens properties inside my program.

Comment: If setting the `current` property doesn't work, you need to work out what you've done wrong to make it not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use threading to set up a listener and kill it after the event.

```py
from threading import Thread
def func():
  #listener mechanism

t1 = Thread(target=func)
t1.start()
```

Then in the mechanism you can use any of the ways in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) article to stop it. This should work in the way you want it to.